# 'Is his own manager' procedure error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a procedure that checks if, after an error in the data, an employee appears among it's managers. I created the procedure but I have an error related to nr (Incorrect syntax near the keyword IF). Why does it appears and how can I correct it. I'm a beginner in using SQL Server so any help is welcomed.

This is the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE IsManager( @Id INT)
 as
    WITH Managers
    AS (
        SELECT id, id_manager 1 AS LEVELC
        FROM [DBO].[employees]
        WHERE id = @Id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT P.id, P.id_manager H.LEVELC+1
        FROM  [DBO].[employees] E
        inner join Ancestors H
            ON E.id=H.id_manager
   )    
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS nr FROM (SELECT * FROM Managers where Managers.id=@Id
    IF nr=0
    PRINT 'Error '
    ELSE
    PRINT 'Your database has no errors'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try that

```
CREATE PROCEDURE IsManager( @Id INT)
 as
    declare @nr int

    WITH Managers(id, id_manager, levelc)
    AS (
        SELECT id, id_manager, 1 AS LEVELC
        FROM [DBO].[employees]
        WHERE id = @Id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT P.id, P.id_manager, H.LEVELC+1
        FROM  [DBO].[employees] E
        inner join Ancestors H
            ON E.id=H.id_manager
   )    

  SELECT @nr = COUNT(*) FROM Managers where Managers.id=@Id
  IF @nr=0
    PRINT 'Error '
  ELSE
    PRINT 'Your database has no errors'
```

Comment: I tried that too. If I do so "object Managers becomes invalid" plus other errors occur

Comment: But how can I reverse that? How how can I write a procedure that finds all it's direct and indirect subordinates?

Comment: Ask another question, add example data, expected output and what you tried so far.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will do so